# @EventListener with @Async in Spring

Tags: spring, asynchronous, event-handling

Trying to enable async event handling combining the `@Async` and `@EventListener` annotations, but I still see that the listener is running in the publishing thread.

The example you can find here:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
class AsyncEventListenerExample {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncEventListenerExample.class);

@Bean
TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}


static class MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent {

    private String id;

    public MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

@Component
static class Receiver {

    @EventListener
    void handleSync(MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent event) {
        logger.info("thread '{}' handling '{}' event", Thread.currentThread(), event);
    }

    @Async
    @EventListener
    void handleAsync(MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent event) {
        logger.info("thread '{}' handling '{}' event", Thread.currentThread(), event);
    }

}

@Component
static class Producer {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public Producer(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void create(String id) {
        publisher.publishEvent(new MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent(id));
    }

    @Async
    public void asynMethod() {
        logger.info("running async method with thread '{}'", Thread.currentThread());
    }
}

}
```

and my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AsyncEventListenerExample.class)
public class AsyncEventListenerExampleTests {

@Autowired
Producer producer;

@Test
public void createEvent() throws InterruptedException {

    producer.create("foo");

    //producer.asynMethod();


    // A chance to see the logging messages before the JVM exists.
    Thread.sleep(2000);

}
}
```

However in logs I see that both `@EventListener`s run in the `main` thread.

```
2016-05-12 08:52:43.184  INFO 18671 --- [           main] c.z.e.async2.AsyncEventListenerExample   : thread 'Thread[main,5,main]' handling 'MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent{id='foo'}' event
2016-05-12 08:52:43.186  INFO 18671 --- [           main] c.z.e.async2.AsyncEventListenerExample   : thread 'Thread[main,5,main]' handling 'MedicalRecordUpdatedEvent{id='foo'}' event
```

The `async` infrastructure is initialised with `@EnableAsync` with an asynchronous `TaskExecutor`.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Could you help?

Thanks.

Using Spring Boot 1.4.2.M2, so Spring 4.3.0.RC1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a regression in Spring Framework 4.3.0.RC1 that leads to that very issue you're having. If you use the SNAPSHOT, your project runs fine.

Comment: Was this regression fixed?

Comment: 5 years ago, yes. If you're experiencing an issue, feel free to raise an issue with a small sample we can run that showcases the problem.

Answer (score 6):

`onTicketUpdatedEvent` runs in also main Thread with Spring Framework 4.2.4 Release as follows.
But it runs in SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor if AsyncConfigurer is not implemented.

```
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ExampleEventListener implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void onTicketUpdatedEvent(TicketEvent ticketEvent) {
        log.debug("received ticket updated event");
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I resolved my issue by configuring task-executor bean as follows.

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
@EventListener
public void onTicketUpdatedEvent(TicketEvent ticketEvent) {
    log.debug("received ticket updated event");
}
```